# UWP - TextBox is missing the line feed (\n) character in Windows 10 build 14393

Tags: c#, uwp

After retargeting my UWP project to Windows 10 build 14393 (Anniversary update) I found that the line feed (**\n**) character is missing from the output Text when I press enter in a TextBox with `AcceptsReturn="True"`. When I retarget back to 10240, pressing enter in the TextBox produces the expected CR+LF characters i.e. **\r\n**.

If this is a feature and not a bug, what can I do to bring back the classic TextBox behavior when pressing enter adds both CR and LF characters to the output Text?

Comment: You may handle it programmatically on KeyDown event i.e. EnterKey. Refer Url -> "https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752054(v=vs.110).aspx"

Comment: As this breaks expected legacy behavior, I'd expect it to be a bug and not a new feature! You can try to report it through the Windows Feedback app, or through the [Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio) website.

Comment: Bug on github: https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/1826

Answer (score 0):

FWIW: I see a similar behavior: my textbox now uses \r instead of \n for newline. I didn't even notice (there's just one screen that's affected)